# How to check password using RegEx using jquery and without keyup function

Tags: html, jquery, regex

I want to make a signup form in which user type password which contains combination of alphabet,letter and length > 6 otherwise form will not submit

here I have shown function specifically for password only but i have other function for other input types and they are working properly but it is not.

```js
$('#password').hide();
var password = false;
$('#user_password').focusout(function() {
  check_password();
});

function check_password() {
  var password = new RegExp(/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?!.*\s).{8,15}$/);
  var password_length = $('#user_password').val().length;
  if (password.test($("#user_password").val()) && password_length > 6) {
    alert("hello");
    $('#password').hide();
  } else {
    $('#password').html('Password should be more than 6 character and should contain a letter and number');
    $('#password').show();
    password = true;
  }
}
$('#signupfrm').submit(function() {

      password = false;
      check_password();
      if (password == false) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="form" name="signupfrm" id="signupfrm" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
  //other input types above password input type
  <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password..." name="user_password" id="user_password" required="">
  <span id="password">
                                            
                                            </span>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-login" name="signup" id="signup" value="Signup">Create My Account</button>

</form>
```

Comment: u realize there is a password input type designed for this purpose?

Comment: I made you a snippet  -it is not working because of invalid syntax

Comment: for other input types i mean to say that for first name,last name and for them i have checked there length and it is working

Answer (score 0):

You likely meant to do this

But you need to fix your regex https://regex101.com/r/ND19JO/1

I suggest this:

```
^(?=.{6,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).*$
```

6 chars one lowerCase, one upperCase and one special char

```js
const passwordRe = new RegExp(/^(?=.{6,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).*$/);
const check_password = function() {
  const pw = $('#user_password').val();
  const pwOK = passwordRe.test(pw);
  $('#pwError').toggle(!pwOK);
  return pwOK;
}

$(function() {
  $('#user_password').focusout(check_password)
  $('#signupfrm').on("submit", function(e) {
    if (!check_password()) e.preventDefault();
  })
})
```

```css
#pwError {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="form" name="signupfrm" id="signupfrm" method="post" action="">
  <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password..." name="user_password" id="user_password" value="bla" required="">
  <span id="pwError">Password should be more than 6 character and should contain a letter and number</span>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-login" name="signup" id="signup" value="Signup">Create My Account</button>
</form>
```

Comment: YES the error is staying even after i have entered letter and number and length>6

Answer (score 0):

If you have the correct regex, you don't have to test separately for the length:

```
var password = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?!.*\s).{7,15}$/;
```

It seems you also do not allow white space in your password. The way to prevent the form from submitting is to execute `event.preventDefault()` in your submit handler if the password is invalid. So the function `check_password` needs to return a flag that will be checked. I have removed the code that hides and unhides the password field to reduce the code to its essence:

```js
function check_password() {
  var password = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?!.*\s).{7,15}$/;
  if (password.test($("#user_password").val())) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    console.log('Password should be more than 6 character and should contain a letter and number and no spaces');
    return false;
  }
}

$(function() {
  $('#signupfrm').submit(function() {
    if (!check_password(event)) {
        event.preventDefault();
     }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="form" name="signupfrm" id="signupfrm" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
  <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password..." name="user_password" id="user_password" required="">
  <span id="password">
                                            
                                            </span>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-login" name="signup" id="signup" value="Signup">Create My Account</button>

</form>
```

Note that you should only attempt to create the `submit` handler once you are sure that the document's elements have been created, i.e. element id `signupform` in this case. That is why that code is placed in a `jQuery.ready()` block (or its shortcut version). See [.ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/).